# how to in django admn after insert get record ID?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like after insert in django admin create a directory like a record ID, how and where can I do this.

I try it in to save_model, but it's not work, Gallery.ID returns None

Model:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    added = models.DateTimeField()
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

And AdminModel

```
class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_on_top = True
    list_filter = ('active',)
    list_display = ('title','active','added')
    ordering = ['-added']
    inlines = [ImagesInline]

    def save_model(self, request, Gallery, form, change):
        if not change:
            Gallery.title = str(Gallery.id)
        Gallery.save()
```

Comment: Don't use `Gallery` as an option to your method - it'll hide the `Gallery` class, and anyway it's misleading as the method is passed an instance, not the class. Do as the documentation suggests, and use `obj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `GalleryAdmin` to this...  You need to `save()` before the `Gallery` instance gets its `id`.

```
def save_model(self, request, Gallery, form, change):
    Gallery.save()
    if not change:
        Gallery.title = str(Gallery.id)
```

Comment: `title` won't be saved. You should call `save()` again.

Answer (score 1):

```
def save_model(self, request, Gallery, form, change):
    if Gallery.id is None:
        Gallery.save()
    if not change:
        Gallery.title = str(Gallery.id)
    Gallery.save()
```

This will do two `save()`'s only the first time.